# Python Flask App: Handling external requests safely

Tags: python, flask, web-applications, python-requests

This is more of a best practice question that I want to solve. I am working on a Flask app that makes external request to get a token etc. If the request is successful I get a JSON file that has the key 'token' or if the request fails I get a JSON file for the error. Here's basic skeleton code:

```
from flask import Flask
import requests

@route('/token')
def gettoken():
    token_response = requests.post(basic_send_url, data=data)

    return token_response['token']
```

I am calling this endpoint from another script. If the request fails I will get an error since the error JSON does not have 'token' key. I have multiple similar requests and I do not want my app to fail due to failure of those requests (suppose if they happen, I want the user to retry or something else). My first question is, whether there's a better Pythonic way for the above code (like using `try` or exception handling). Second, what are the best practices for the above situations in production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding different options, I decided to go with the following one:

```
@route('/token') 
def gettoken():     
    token_response = requests.post(basic_send_url, data=data)
    token_value = token_response.get('token')  # .get() does not raise an error if the key doesn't exist; it returns None
    if token_value:
        return token_value
    return 400, "Bad request"
```

So the key is to use `get()` function. It is simple and allows me to handle all similar errors as "Bad request" in my main script and redirect users to a single page designed for bad requests.